# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I failed to see what I've done wrong in my code. I tried all possible solution I found in google but still the same error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

```
 Private Sub Add_row_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add_row.Click

        Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\carol\Documents\VBexcel\customer masterlist.xlsx;Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""
        Dim selectStatement As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(selectStatement, connectionString)
        Dim ds As New DataSet("[Sheet1$]")
        adapter.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "[Sheet1$]")
        adapter.Fill(ds, "[Sheet1$]")

        Dim excelData As New DataTable
        DataGridView_excel.DataSource = excelData

        excelData = ds.Tables("[Sheet1$]")
        Dim drCurrent As DataRow
        drCurrent = excelData.NewRow
        drCurrent("First Name") = TextBox1.Text
        drCurrent("Last Name") = TextBox2.Text
        drCurrent("Address") = TextBox3.Text
        drCurrent("Number") = TextBox4.Text
        ' more fields go here

        excelData.Rows.Add(drCurrent)
        Dim objCommandBuilder As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter.Update(ds, "[Sheet1$]")


 End Sub
```

this code is where I'm getting errors:

```
adapter.Update(ds, "[Sheet1$]")
```

Comment: your code doesn't even include `Insert` statement,maybe u forgot to add it ?

Comment: You have spaces in your column names so that's going to cause an issue when the command builder generates the action commands.  A command builder doesn't escape column names by default so, if it's required, you have to specify it by setting the `QuotePrefix` and `QuoteSuffix` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank @jmcilhinney for tips. it works!!

Private Sub Add_row_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add_row.Click

```
    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\carol\Documents\VBexcel\customer masterlist.xlsx;Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""
    Dim selectStatement As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(selectStatement, connectionString)
    Dim ds As New DataSet("[Sheet1$]")
    adapter.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "[Sheet1$]")
    adapter.Fill(ds, "[Sheet1$]")

    Dim excelData As New DataTable
    DataGridView_excel.DataSource = excelData

    excelData = ds.Tables("[Sheet1$]")
    Dim drCurrent As DataRow
    drCurrent = excelData.NewRow
    drCurrent("First Name") = TextBox1.Text
    drCurrent("Last Name") = TextBox2.Text
    drCurrent("Address") = TextBox3.Text
    drCurrent("Number") = TextBox4.Text
    ' more fields go here

    excelData.Rows.Add(drCurrent)
    Dim objCommandBuilder As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
    objCommandBuilder.QuotePrefix = "["
    objCommandBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]"
    adapter.Update(ds, "[Sheet1$]")
    DataGridView_excel.DataSource = excelData

End Sub
```

this excel files is not mine but I have to manipulate the data without changing its original format